# how to calculate the actual road distance between two latitude and longitude in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, geolocation

how to calculate the actual road distance between two latitude and longitude in angular

**I use this but I want for actual road distance between two latitude and longitude**

```
var radlat1 = Math.PI * this.tripDetail.pickUp.location.lat/180;
      var radlat2 = Math.PI * this.currentLocation.lat/180;
      var theta = this.tripDetail.pickUp.location.lon - this.currentLocation.lon;
      var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
      var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
      if (dist > 1) {
        dist = 1;
      }
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      // if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
      // if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
      this.locationToRetailer = dist * 1.609344
```

Please give me a solution.....

Answer (score 0):

**This code makes a request to the Google Maps Directions API and extracts the road distance from the response**

```
const origin = `${this.currentLocation.lat},${this.currentLocation.lon}`;
const destination = `${this.tripDetail.pickUp.location.lat},${this.tripDetail.pickUp.location.lon}`;
const apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

// Make a request to the Directions API
const response = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${origin}&destination=${destination}&key=${apiKey}`);
const data = await response.json();

// Extract the road distance from the response
const distanceInMeters = data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
const distanceInKilometers = distanceInMeters / 1000;
this.locationToRetailer = distanceInKilometers;
```

Comment: I am getting this error -  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: If you have control over the server code, you can add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the response. In the case of Node.js, you can use a middleware like cors to enable CORS for your server. Install the cors package using npm